# Odoo 9 is not running tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, odoo, odoo-9

I try to write test for odoo module.
Module has structure:

```
/pr_mobile
|--->conttrollers
|--->demo
|--->models
|--->security
|--->tests
....|----> __init__.py
....|----> test_mobileproduct.py
|--->views
__init__.py
...
```

**init**.py:

```
from . import tests
```

tests/**init**.py

```
import test_mobileproduct
```

tests/test_mobileproduct.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
from openerp.tests import common
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError


class TestMobileProduct(common.TransactionCase):

    def test_get_maket(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
    def test_get_maket2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
    def test_get_maket3(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)
    def test_get_maket4(self):
        self.assertEqual5(1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I run test with this commands:

> ./odoo.py --addons-path=addons,openerp/addons,openerp/my-addons -d
>   pr_odoo_v9 --db-filter="^pr_odoo_v9"  -u pr_mobile --test-enable
>   --log-level=test

And result is:

```
skif@ubuntu-desktop:/opt/odoo$ ./odoo.py --addons-path=addons,openerp/addons,openerp/my-addons -d pr_odoo_v9 --db-filter="^pr_odoo_v9"  -u pr_mobile --test-enable --log-level=test
2019-04-10 15:11:48,708 8919 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2019-04-10 15:11:48,709 8919 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/skif/.local/share/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', u'/opt/odoo/openerp/addons', u'/opt/odoo/openerp/my-addons']
2019-04-10 15:11:48,709 8919 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2019-04-10 15:11:48,774 8919 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2019-04-10 15:11:48,780 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2019-04-10 15:11:48,788 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2019-04-10 15:11:49,541 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: loading 64 modules...
2019-04-10 15:11:49,560 8919 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2019-04-10 15:11:49,579 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2019-04-10 15:11:50,252 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.module: module pr_mobile: creating or updating database tables
/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py:451: UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if cols[k][key] != vals[key]:
2019-04-10 15:11:50,601 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: loading pr_mobile/views/views.xml
2019-04-10 15:11:50,970 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: loading pr_mobile/views/saleorder.xml
2019-04-10 15:11:51,017 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: loading pr_mobile/views/templates.xml
2019-04-10 15:11:51,021 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_translation: module pr_mobile: no translation for language ru
2019-04-10 15:11:51,171 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: 64 modules loaded in 1.63s, 5 queries
2019-04-10 15:11:51,626 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2019-04-10 15:11:51,628 8919 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.modules.loading: All post-tested in 0.00s, 0 queries
```

Why are tests not running? In db present data from production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `at_install` or `post_install` for the tests to run at installation or upgrading

```
class TestMobileProduct(common.TransactionCase):
    at_install = True
    post_install = True
```